# exercise with salaries on python 3 - code doesn't run properly, no syntax errors

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing this little exercise that consists of adding a bonus to salary based on performance and determining how employees performed base on the qualification:

1. unacceptable = 0
2. acceptable = 0.4
3. top performance = 0.6

This is what I have so far:

```
   value_number = float(input('write down the person qualification'))

  def salary_and_performance(value):
    salary = 2400 + 2400 * value_number
    if value_number == 0:
        return salary
        print('unacceptable')
    elif value_number == 0.4:
        return salary
        print('acceptable')
    elif value_number == 0.6:
        return salary
        print('top performance')
    else:
        print('invalid value')

 salary_and_performance(value_number)
```

When I run my code it doesn't return any data. Only a black space displays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

print('inaceptable') ,print('acceptable') etc. will never run besause they are located after return statement. First print and then return. Or you might want not to return anything in that case, I don't know the purpose of your function.

Replace all instances of `value_number` within your function with `value` because that is the name of your argument

```
value_number = float(input('write down the person calification'))


def salary_and_performance(value):
    salary = 2400 + 2400 * value
    if value == 0:
        print('inaceptable')
        return salary
    elif value == 0.4:
        print('acceptable')
        return salary
    elif value == 0.6:
        print('top performance')
        return salary
    else:
        print('invalid value')

salary_and_performance(value_number)
```

Comment: The propose of the function is to return the type of performace that the employe had and the salary that he would be getting with that performance.

Comment: but after putting print first the function doesnt return the amount of money thet the employe must recive, any idea of why is not returning the salary?

Comment: Because you mixed up the parameters

Comment: value and value_number

Comment: Test this code, you can comment out prints if they bother you to see if function returns desired value.

Comment: it still gives me the same problem

Comment: Function returns nothing? For which input?

Comment: write down the person calification0
inaceptable

Comment: It works fine for me. After the message enter a number and press enter

Comment: yeah but when i do that it only returns acceptable for me, i will keep trying to fix it

Comment: it does run properly there, seens like my python is the problem, thx for helping me